# The use of soundness in the Kritchman-Raz proof and Berry's paradox

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness, kolmogorov-complexity

In the [Kritchman-Raz paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4974) the authors recall Chaitin's proof of a version of the first incompleteness theorem (italics are mine):

> Chaitin’s incompleteness theorem states that for any rich enough
> consistent mathematical theory [$T$], there exists a (large enough) integer
> $L$ (depending on the theory and on the programming language that is
> used to define Kolmogorov complexity), such that, for any integer $x$,
> the statement “$K(x) > L$” cannot be proved within the theory [$T$].
>
> The proof given by Chaitin is as follows. Let $L$ be a large enough
> integer. Assume for a contradiction that for some integer $x$, there is
> a proof for the statement “$K(x) > L$”. Let $w$ be the first proof (say,
> according to the lexicographic order) for a statement of the form
> $“K(x) > L”$. Let $z$ be the integer $x$ such that $w$ proves “$K(x) > L$”. It
> is easy to give a computer program that outputs $z$: the program
> enumerates all possible proofs $w$, one by one, and for the first $w$ that
> proves a statement of the form “$K(x) > L$”, the program outputs $x$ and
> stops. The length of this program is a constant $+ \log L$. Thus, if $L$ is
> large enough, the Kolmogorov complexity of z is less than $L$. *Since $w$
> is a proof for “$K(z) > L$” (which is a false statement), we conclude
> that the theory is inconsistent.*

Some questions:

1. This proof seems to use the stronger assumption that $T$ is sound instead of just consistent (see italics). What is going on here? I guess you can proceed as follows: the argument establishes that $T \vdash K(x) > L$ implies $K(x) = k$ for some $k < L$. But $K(x) = k$ is $\Sigma_1$, so also $T \vdash K(x) = k$ and hence $T \vdash \bot$. Therefore the consistency of $T$ implies that $T \nvdash K(x) > L$ (as we wished). Is this the implicit argument? I don't find it very clear.
2. The authors also say that this is a formalization of Berry's paradox using Kolmogorov Complexity. Why is that? Berry's paradox is:

> Consider the expression “the smallest positive integer not definable
> in under eleven words”. This expression defines that integer in under
> eleven words.

So a formalization would be:

> Consider the program that searches for the smallest $x$ such that $K(x) > C$. This program has size less than $C$ (if $C$ is large enough).

The problem here is of course that $K(x)$ is not computable. But how does this relate to Chaitin's proof?

Comment: Where does "sound" appear in the proof ? I only find "consistent"

Comment: The relation to Berry's paradox comes from the self-reference. We construct a program that outputs a number with a complexity larger than that of the given program which gives a contradiction.

Comment: The uncomputability of the complexity can be shown analogue to the above proof : We assume that the complexity is computable. Then, there is a turing machine that can compute the complexity of every number. But if the complexity of the number is large enough, it exceeds the complexity of the assumed turing machine.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your comment! Soundness doesn't appear in the proof, that is my point, they author (on my interpretation) either confuser or conflate soundness and consistency. You need something like my argument to make the move to consistency (or at least I think, hence the question).

Comment: @Peter With respect to the computability of $K(x)$: isn't that exactly what I write? (But this isn't really my question anyway)

Comment: @Peter: You need to unmute your speakers if you want to have sound. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: $(1)$, you have the right idea: there is indeed an implicit argument that mere consistency is enough. However, what you've written isn't exactly right since "$K(x)=L$" is not in general $\Sigma_1$ (it's merely $\Sigma_1\wedge\Pi_1$). Rather, you want to focus on the sentence "$K(x)\le L$:" this is $\Sigma_1$ since it amounts to the existence of a single computation, and so our theory can verify each of its true instances. So if in reality $K(x)\le L$ but we prove $K(x)>L$ then we're inconsistent. (More snappily, this amounts to saying: consistency implies $\Pi_1$-soundness since the theory in question is $\Sigma_1$-complete, and "$K(x)>L$" is $\Pi_1$.)

Re: $(2)$, the point is that if $T$ were to prove enough Kolmogorov lower bounds then we could use it to whip up a "computable version" of your idea. Specifically, consider the machine $M$ which on input $c$ searches through $T$-proofs for a proof of the form "$K(n)>c$" for some $n$, halting and outputting the corresponding $n$ once it finds one. Assuming that for each $a$ there is some $b$ such that $T\vdash K(b)>a$, this machine always halts, but this gives a contradiction once $c$ is large enough. You can think of $M$ as - on input $c$ - looking for "the natural number which **most obviously** takes $>c$-many symbols to **concretely** describe," where "concretely" refers to $T$-provability and "most obviously" refers to our search through proofs (the idea being that shorter proof = more obviousness).

Comment: But now I'm actually slightly confused: we know that there exists $x$ such that $K(x) > L$, no matter how large $L$. So for this $x$ we have $K(x) = C$ where $C > L$. This is $\Sigma_1$, so $T \vdash K(x) = C$. Also clearly $T \vdash C > L$, hence $T \vdash K(x) > L$?

Comment: Now that I think further about it: is $K(x) = L$ really $\Sigma_1$? It appears that to express the minimality you need to say that all less complicated Turing machines either don't output $x$ _or don't halt_, but "don't halt" is $\Pi_1$, isn't it? So then my argument isn't implicit (because it's wrong).

Comment: Also $K(x) > L$ _is_ $\Pi_1$, I think, so we can use the theorem you mentioned, that for PA "consistency $\Leftrightarrow$ $\Pi_1$-soundness", directly (probably you also meant this).

Comment: @Jori No, $K(x)=L$ is not $\Sigma_1$, and I misread your implicit argument: I thought you'd looked at the formula $K(x)\le L$, which is indeed $\Sigma_1$. The point is that $\mathsf{PA}$ (or whatever) *can* verify that $K(x)\le L$ by exhibiting a single appropriate computation, and that's enough for the implicit argument you describe. The $\Sigma_1$-ness of $K(x)\le L$ is enough for us (and this is how I misread your argument), and this is what they have in mind.

Comment: @Jori I've edited to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and edit. I'm confident I understand it now!

Comment: I've been reading this again; I don't think I've understood your answer to (2). I'm not sure I see the analogy between what you write and Berry's paradox. If you have time, I'd still like to know (even though this question is slightly dated). Many thanks.

Comment: @Jori Ignoring the connection with Berry's paradox at first, does the math in that part make sense (or is there a point you'd like me to clarify)?

Comment: I think so; at least up to (and including) "but this gives a contradiction once $c$ is large enough."

Comment: @Jori OK, so the remaining sentence is the comparison between this and Berry's paradox. Berry's paradox asks us about "the smallest number which takes $>c$-many symbols to describe" (for appropriately large $c$), whereas I'm interpreting the above as "the first-discovered number which takes $>c$-many symbols to provably describe." So we've replaced "least" with "first-discovered" - this refers to the search through proofs - and we've replaced "describe" with "provably describe." The latter shift is fairly unsurprising; we need to do things like this quite frequently. (cont'd)

Comment: The former is really just an instance of a more general observation: that all the word "least" is doing in the Berry paradox is singling out (via few symbols) a particular element of the set of numbers not describable with $\le c$-many symbols. "Second-least" would also result in a paradox, as would (say) "the smallest amongst those with the fewest $3$s in their decimal expansion as possible." Here we're using the proof-search process to pick an appropriate member.

Comment: I see; and your program $M$ is a description of this number in less than $c$ symbols, hence paradox (or here rather contradiction, showing that not all Kolmogorov Complexity bounds can be proved in $T$)?

Comment: Also, don't you mean  "the first-discovered number which provably takes $>\! c$-many symbols to describe" ? Otherwise, (I think) it might sound like you mean you are looking for an $n$ such that there is a $T$-proof of $K(n) = d$, where $d > c$. Or do I misunderstand you?